# Angularjs 2/4 Form validation with Complex formbuilder

Tags: javascript, angular

I am building a form with complex FormBuilder.

```
this.myForm = this._fb.group({
        name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
        addresses: this._fb.group({
          street: ['pp', Validators.required],
          state: {
            city: ['New York']
          },
          postcode: ['']
        })
});
```

In a nested form, I have a field with can update city. How can I use formControlName for it.

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/Repdb3cn7luWkSQGZk8n?p=preview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just make `state` as a formGroup, and inside that the form control `city`:

```
    this.myForm = this._fb.group({
        name: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5)]],
        addresses: this._fb.group({
          street: ['pp', Validators.required],
          state: this._fb.group({
            city: ['New York']
          }),
          postcode: ['']
        })
    });
```

template:

```
<div formGroupName="state">
  <input formControlName="city"/>
</div>
```

Your forked

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DlPEP3Guu8zjGbXFavz8?p=preview)